# Is there any private API that gives WiFi signal strength in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, signal-strength

I want to find the WiFi signal strength in iOS 7. I know we cannot do it from any public API, but is there any private API we can use in iOS 7?

I read that in iOS 5, we can use private API only when it the device is jailbroken. Is this also the case for iOS 7?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've been able to find out, the private APIs behave differently in iOS7 (and I haven't been able to find out how yet :( ). However you need to specify what you mean by iOS7. You should be able to build your app for iOS5, and run it on an iOS7 device, unless you also need access to specific iOS6/7 functionality...